# How to fix "errno":"ENOTFOUND" error in smtp configuration using express js

Tags: express, proxy, smtp, nodemailer

I am trying to configure node mailer in express js application. During the time of sending mail, I got an error ENOTFOUND.

My smpt configurations are,

`smtpServer: {
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        user: "email@gmail.com",
        pass: "password",
        fromName: "",
        fromAddress: ""
    }`

Error :

`{"errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ECONNECTION","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"smtp.gmail.com","host":"smtp.gmail.com","port":587,"command":"CONN","meta":{"errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ECONNECTION","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"smtp.gmail.com","host":"smtp.gmail.com","port":587,"command":"CONN"}}`

I suspect this error came because of proxy issues. So, I checked the smpt hostname in my machine nslookup table.

That is returned following result:

`$ nslookup smtp.gmail.com`

`Server:        127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find smtp.gmail.com: No answer`

Other than else what I missed here?

Comment: when I ran `nslookup` smtp.gmail.com` i got an answer. i think your DNS server not work

Comment: @ShayMoshe Thanks for your update. Do you know how to resolve this domain address?